# OpenLDAP SSL Cerificates

Tags: ssl, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to implement SSL to my OpenLDAP installation on CentOS 7 and can't seem to get the right certificates in the correct fields.  I'm a little confused by the issuers naming conventions.  I'm sure this is an LDAP + SSL newbie question :)

Self signed certs are named as follows

```
server.key
server.crt
server.csr
```

The issuer has provided me with

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
SAAddTrustCA.crt
SADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
my_domain_name.crt
```

In my mod_ssl.ldif I have

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/SADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/server.key
```

I've tried several combinations of this without success.  I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking here.  When running

```
# slapd -d -1
```

I get the following output, which I'm sure means something along the lines of bad/mismatched key

```
55d22d8e connection_get(15)
55d22d8e connection_get(15): got connid=1000
55d22d8e connection_read(15): checking for input on id=1000
ber_get_next
ldap_read: want=8, got=8
  0000:  16 03 03 00 cf 01 00 00                            ........
55d22d8e ber_get_next on fd 15 failed errno=34 (Numerical result out of range)
55d22d8e connection_read(15): input error=-2 id=1000, closing.
55d22d8e connection_closing: readying conn=1000 sd=15 for close
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem, it was two fold.

First, I should have been using TLS not SSL

Second, the correct settings are:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/SecureServerCA.crt
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/mydomain.crt
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/server.key
```

Answer (score 0):

Also be sure that openldap user have access to the directory/files